# How do you populate a checkbox group from a SQL query

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs

I have a query that returns all the column titles in a table. 
I want to populate the values box labels for each checkbox in my group with the values returned from the query. the id node will be the value and the text node will be the checkbox label.

The query is initiated by the ActionName in the store load event.

Here is my code

```
{
            xtype       : 'checkboxgroup',
            fieldLabel  : 'Column Names',
            id          : 'chkColumnNames',
            itemId      : 'chkColumnNames',
            cls         : 'x-check-group-alt',
            // Distribute controls across 5 even columns, filling each row
            // from left to right before starting the next row
            columns: 5,
            store          : Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                model    : 'Personnel.ART.String.ChoiceList',       
                autoLoad : true,
                sorters: [{
                    property: 'text',
                    direction: 'ASC'
                }],
                proxy    : {
                    type     : 'ajax',
                    url      : IXYZ.portal.path + 'IXYZDBService.asmx/jsonSQLActions',
                    actionMethods : {read : 'POST'},
                    extraParams : {
                        AppAcronym      : IXYZ.application.acronym, 
                        WFAcronym       : IXYZ.workflow.acronym,
                        Process_id      : -1,
                        ActionName      : 'ART.SELECT.ADHOC.COMBINED_PERSONNEL.COLUMN.NAMES',
                        suppressLog     : true,
                        tokenProcessing : 'False'
                    },
                    reader   : {type : 'xml', record : 'row'}
                },
                listeners      : {
                    load: function(store, records, successful) {
                        columnNamesCheckbox = Ext.getCmp('chkColumnNames');
                        var columnNameItems = [];

                        for(var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
                             columnNameItems.push({id: records[i].data.id, boxLabel: records[i].data.text}); 
                        }
                    }
                }
            }),
            items: [

            ]
        }
```

Here is the xml from the query

```
<row id="PersonnelID" text="PersonnelID" />
<row id="UserID" text="UserID" />
<row id="FirstName" text="FirstName" />
<row id="LastName" text="LastName" />
<row id="MiddleName" text="MiddleName" />
<row id="PreferredName" text="PreferredName" />
<row id="HomePhone" text="HomePhone" />
<row id="WorkEmail" text="WorkEmail" />
<row id="bActing" text="bActing" />
<row id="HomeAddress" text="HomeAddress" />
<row id="GSLevel" text="GSLevel" />
```

Comment: Here is what worked for me.I referenced the checkbox group by id since I was running code from the store then looped through the records and used checkboxgroup.add to populate the checkbox group

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me.I referenced the checkbox group by id since I was running code from the store then looped through the records and used checkboxgroup.add to populate the checkbox group

```
{
            xtype       : 'checkboxgroup',
            fieldLabel  : 'Column Names',
            id          : 'chkColumnNames',
            itemId      : 'chkColumnNames',
            cls         : 'x-check-group-alt',
            // Distribute controls across 5 even columns, filling each row
            // from left to right before starting the next row
            columns: 5,
            store          : Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                model    : 'Personnel.ART.String.ChoiceList',       
                autoLoad : true,
                sorters: [{
                    property: 'text',
                    direction: 'ASC'
                }],
                proxy    : {
                    type     : 'ajax',
                    url      : ICWF.portal.path + 'ICWFDBService.asmx/jsonSQLActions',
                    actionMethods : {read : 'POST'},
                    extraParams : {
                        AppAcronym      : ICWF.application.acronym, 
                        WFAcronym       : ICWF.workflow.acronym,
                        Process_id      : -1,
                        ActionName      : 'ART.SELECT.ADHOC.COMBINED_PERSONNEL.COLUMN.NAMES',
                        suppressLog     : true,
                        tokenProcessing : 'False'
                    },
                    reader   : {type : 'xml', record : 'row'}
                },
                listeners      : {
                    load: function(store, records, successful) {
                    var checkboxgroup = Ext.getCmp('chkColumnNames');

                        for(var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
                             //ICWF.reports.itemArray.push({id: records[i].data.id, boxLabel: records[i].data.text});
                              checkboxgroup.add({
                                xtype: 'checkbox',
                                inputValue: records[i].data.id,
                                boxLabel: records[i].data.text,
                                //checked: rec.get(cField),
                                //name: 'fName'
                            });
                        }
                        debugger;
                    }
                }
            }),
            items: []
        }
```